# Logstash to output events in Elasticsearch bulk API data format

Tags: logstash

Is is possible to have Logstash to output events in Elasticsearch bulk API data format?

The idea is to do some heavy parsing on many machines (without direct connectivity to the ES node) and then feed the data manually into ES.

Thank for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logstash is a single-line type of system, and the bulk format is a multi-line format.  Here are two ideas:

1) see if the file{} output message_format can contain a newline.  This would allow you to output the meta data line and then the data line.

2) use logstash's clone{} to make a copy of each event.  In the "original" event, use the file{} output with a message_format that looks like the first line of the bulk output (index, type, id).  In the cloned copy, the default file{} output might work (or use the message_format with the exact format you need).

Comment: thanks for the clarification and suggestions. I guess logstash does not directly support this capability and I need to go through the workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you need change the `flush_size` in Logstash with your value:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-flush_size

Or send metadata in file using **json** codec and afterload directly on elasticsearch
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-file.html

Comment: The 'flush_size' is used to directly feed Elasticsearch. As for `file` module, you need to do some manipulation to get the desired bulk API format - the 'how to manipulate' is what I want to know.